# React-Native Type-Script for Android: Button does not listen to onPress

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, button

I followed the instructions to set up a development environment on MacOs, using Android Studio and react-native following the instructions here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

I initialized a bare example project using this line

npx react-native@latest init TTG

The example works pretty fine.

Then I added a function like this to the example:

```
function logIt(){

    console.log("Foobar");

}
```

And a Button to call the function:

```
    <Button
      title="Logit"
      accessibilityLabel="log it"
      onPress={logIt()}
      color="blue"
    />
```

When I run the app

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

the console shows

```
 LOG  Foobar
```

Which is the first thing that seems strange to me.

When I press the button in the simulator, the console does not show anything. The second strange behavior I do not understand.

This is the full code - I stripped it down to remove all the example stuff, but the result remains the same: The button does not trigger the function:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

function logIt(){

console.log("Foobar");

}

function App(): JSX.Element {

  return (

    <SafeAreaView>
            <Button
              title="Logit"
              accessibilityLabel="log it"
              onPress={logIt()}
              color="blue"
            />

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's either onPress={logIt} or onPress={() => logIt()}, otherwise your function will be called out when creating the element.

Comment: Understand. And it's working now. Can this be explained? I'm coming from at least 20 years of pure JavaScript web-development but TypeScript is new to me.

Comment: For the record: I'm trying classes now, using arrow function works with methods of  a class. Just the method call (class.method) returns a "TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes".